# Select option multiple values for google maps long and latt

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables

I've a form for taxi booking. First select box is to choose start point. Second one is for end point. Both have values of id numbers which i need to keep.

I'm trying to make the route when select values are selected. If i put long&latt to select option values, google maps is working fine, drawing the destination. But i need to keep the destination id's as values in the select option values and putting 2 values together in option is not working.

Here is what i'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapCanvas;var directionDisplay;var directionsService;
var stepDisplay;var markerArray=[];
function initialize(){directionsService=new 
google.maps.DirectionsService();
var d=new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var a={zoom:12,scrollwheel:false,zoomControl:true,
panControl:false,disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
enableTouchUI:true,mapTypeControl:false,
streetViewControl:false,mapTypeId:google.maps.
MapTypeId.ROADMAP,center:d};
mapCanvas=new google.maps.Map(document.
getElementById("map"),a);var b=[{featureType:"all"}];
mapCanvas.setOptions({styles:b});var c=new google.maps.
Polyline({strokeColor:"#6495ED",strokeOpacity:0.9,
strokeWeight:6});directionsDisplay=new google.maps.
DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions:c});var k={map:mapCanvas,
suppressMarkers:true,polylineOptions:c};directionsDisplay=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(k);calcRoute()}function calcRoute(){for(i=0;i<markerArray.length;i++){
markerArray[i].setMap(null)}markerArray=[];
var b=document.getElementById("start").value;
var c=document.getElementById("end").value;
var a=origin:b,destination:c,travelMode:google.maps.
DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING};directionsService.route(a,function(f,e){if(e==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){var d=document.getElementById("map_");directionsDisplay.
setDirections(f);showSteps(f)}})}function 
showSteps(e){var a=e.routes[0].legs[0];for(
var c=0;c<a.steps.length;c++){var d="0.png";if(c==0){d="/transfer/1.png"}
var b=new google.maps.Marker({position:a.steps[c].
start_point,map:mapCanvas,icon:d});markerArray.push(b)}var b=new google.maps.Marker({position:a.steps[c-1].
end_point,map:mapCanvas,icon:"/transfer/2.png"});
markerArray.push(b)}google.maps.event.
addDomListener(window,"load",initialize);</script>
</script>
```

```
<div id="panel"><center>
<b>Transfer From: </b>
<select id="start" name="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value='37.24007,27.673273' selected>Bodrum Milas Airport</option>
  <option value="38.297999,27.142523">Izmir Airport</option>
  <option value="36.731378,28.79478">Dalaman Airport</option>
</select>


<b>Transfer To: </b>
<select id="end" name="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="37.034419,27.430542" selected>Bodrum</option>
  <option value="37.104419,27.28905">Yalikavak</option>
  <option value="37.003958,27.258495">Turgutreis</option>
</select></center>
</div>
</form>
```

This form and script works fine but i must put destination id's instead of long&latt's. "Transfer to" (2nd select box) is getting all the values from database and matching them to continue to rest of the form.

Any idea how can i get the map work?

In my way of thinking if i can write a JavaScript like;

""if select option is A, var.b = 38.4408,27.152535"", ""if B var.b= another long&latt""

and get that result into ""var b=document.getElementById("start").value;"" in the maps js

i guess i'll get it run. Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Your JS is unreadable as writen inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use another attribute to store the latLng's, e.g.:

```
<option value="someID" latlng="37.24007,27.673273">Bodrum Milas Airport</option>
```

To access these attributes use:

```
var b=document.getElementById("start")
 .options[document.getElementById("start").selectedIndex].getAttribute('latLng');

var c=document.getElementById("end")
 .options[document.getElementById("end").selectedIndex].getAttribute('latLng');
```